# Confusion in 9 patch image

Tags: android, png, nine-patch

Only png image can be converted into 9 patch ?

Correct me if i did something wrong . I converted jpg image into png by paint .
and then changed extension to .9.png so that it can be converted to 9patch image by android studio . I converted that image into 9 patch through android studio .But when i did clean and build it gives error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Please help

Below is my xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="myresolver.faisal.home.com.myresolver.MainActivity">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/fear_72"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try removing `.9` from the file name in android studio.

Answer (score 1):

1. **At first check your 9 Patch Images .** Make sure its properly patched or not .

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. Some file
>   crunching failed, see logs for details

You can add this in your `build.gradle` section

```
 android 
{ 
  aaptOptions
   {
   cruncherEnabled = false
   } 
}
```

You can visit here

> https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Comment: i did it all once again . and it does not show any error but when i give width and height to match parent . image is streched fully . Whats wrong there

Comment: @FaisalAhmed Okay . That is another case . You can share your xml

Comment: add `android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"`

Comment: Your parent is `match_parent`  thats why . Let me inform  its working or not

Comment: Its works fine now. But even image which is not 9 patch is also working in the same way  . Then whats difference in them they both are working in same way . And what android:scaleType="centerInside" does

Comment: What i want is when i use image as background image logo should not be streched .However it should occupy whole screen . for example my logo background colour is green .Then green colour should occupy whole screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117684/discussion-between-intellij-amiya-and-faisalahmed).

Comment: indeed . then `android:adjustViewBounds`

Comment: can u help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854909/can-fonts-and-its-size-can-be-changed-from-xml-in-android